# Open with redirect to localhost oauth2callback

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I support Google Drive SDK 'Open with' at my Go AppEngine based app. Everything works fine for my deployed app. But I cannot setup a valid local AppEngine development setup.
The local AppEngine server runs on http://localhost:8080, therefore my callback for the 'Open with' (Authentication is on) is http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback. But this is not a valid 'Open URL' at the Drive SDK settings (console.developers.google.com). So what's the right setup? Is it not possible to develop 'Open with' functionality with a local AppEngine dev environment?

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Jens,
It's possible to work with OAuth locally but it requires some work, consider that "localhost" means something different for every computer, and that's why it's valid only in a local context. That's why the console does not allow that value.

If you really need to get that callback on your local server you'll need to make your PC's "address" unique and globally accessible, meaning you'll probably have to setup a static IP or Dyniamic DNS and redirect that to your PC so the OAuth provider has a fixed address to locate your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your /etc/hosts (or windows equivalent) file. Find the line that says

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and add (say) mydevserver.me.com

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mydevserver.me.com
```

You can then configure mydevsserver.me.com in the Google API Console.

Comment: @jfrederich Welcome to StackOverflow. The etiquette here is to accept an Answer as correct, rather than post a thanks comment. That way others who have the same problem can quickly identify the solution.